# Schwartz book: Heisenberg equation of motion for quantum fields (equation 7.28)

Tags: operators, hamiltonian, time-evolution, s-matrix-theory, unitarity

In his book "Quantum field theory and the standard model", section 7.2 "Hamiltonian derivation" (of the Feynman rules), Schwartz states that the equations of motion $i\partial_t\phi(x)=[\phi,H]$ have the formal solution (eq 7.27)

$$
\phi(\vec x, t) = S(t,t_0)^\dagger\phi(\vec x)S(t, t_0)\tag{7.27}
$$
where $S$ is the time evolution operator for the momentum eigenstates, and it satisfies
$$
i\partial_t S(t, t_0)=H(t)S(t,t_0).\tag{7.28}
$$

I tried to justify this expression, but I didn't manage. Here what I tried.

From $i\partial_t\phi(x)=[\phi(x),H(t)]$ I get
$$
i\partial_t\phi(x) = i\partial_t[S^\dagger(t,t_0) \phi(\vec x)S(t,t_0)] = 
(i\partial_t S^\dagger(t,t_0)) \phi(\vec x)S(t,t_0) + S^\dagger(t,t_0)\phi(\vec x)(i\partial_t S(t,t_0)) =
[S^\dagger(t,t_0)\phi(\vec x)S(t,t_0), H(t)]
$$

Using the commutator identity, I expand the commutator on the rhs:
$$
(i\partial_t S^\dagger) \phi(\vec x)S + S^\dagger\phi(\vec x)(i\partial_t S)  = S^\dagger\phi(\vec x)[S,H] + [S^\dagger\phi(\vec x), H]S = S^\dagger\phi SH - S^\dagger\phi HS + S^\dagger\phi HS - HS^\dagger\phi S = S^\dagger\phi SH - HS^\dagger\phi S 
$$

For the lhs to be equal to the rhs I have to require:
$$
i\partial_t S = SH
$$
$$
i\partial_t S^\dagger = -HS^\dagger
$$

But Schwartz claim is $i\partial_t S = HS$ and in general $S$ does not commute with $H$. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the confusion.

In the derivation, I always assumed that the Hamiltonian is in the Heisenberg representation. If I now express my last equation, $i\partial_t S = SH_H$ (the $H$ subscript stands for Heisenberg), in the Schrödinger representation I get
$$
\partial_t S = SH_H = SS^\dagger H_S S = H_S S
$$

So the time evolution given by Schwartz is the time evolution of the S operator using the Hamiltonian in the Schrödinger representation.